# How can I align a Dropdow list in kivy to the main button's center?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've created a DropDown list but I want just a tiny arrow to open it. When I click the arrow the list opens and the itens have to be bigger than the arrow button. So I've set auto_width to false. The problem is now the list is aligned at the left side of the arrow button. I wanted it to be in the center, like a halign = 'center' option.  But it doesnt work and I couldnt find one that does.

Here is the python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown

from kivy.uix.button import Button
# from kivy.clock import Clock
# from crialista import running
# from time import sleep


class MainWindow(Screen):
    min = ObjectProperty(None)
    seg = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.min_down = DropDown()
        self.sec_down = DropDown()

        for x in range(61):
            btn_min = Button(text=str(x), font_size=30, size_hint_y=None, height=50)                btn_min.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.minute(btn.text))
            btn_min.bind(on_release=lambda dismiss: self.min_down.dismiss())
            self.min_down.add_widget(btn_min)

        self.min_down.auto_width = False

    def minute(self, texto):
        self.min.text = texto


class NumericInput(TextInput):

    def insert_text(self, string, from_undo=False):
        new_text = self.text + string
        self.input_filter = 'int'
        if new_text != "":
            try:
                if int(new_text) >= 0:
                    self.text = new_text
                    if int(new_text) > 60:
                        self.text = "60"
                    if len(new_text) > 2:
                        self.text = new_text[:-1]

            except ValueError:
                TextInput.insert_text(self, "", from_undo=from_undo)


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("teste.kv")


class TesteApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TesteApp().run()
```

And the kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    min: min

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_x': .27, 'center_y': .6}
            size_hint: .03, .05
            on_release: root.min_down.open(self)

        NumericInput:
            id: min

            pos_hint:{'center_x': .4, 'center_y': .6}
            size_hint: .15, .1
            input_filter: "int"
            hint_text: '00'
            hint_text_color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
            font_size: (root.width/25 + root.height/25)
            halign: "center"
            multiline: False
```

In this example code i've put just a tiny box but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method in your `MainWindow` class to do what you want. Instead of calling the `DropDownList` `open()` method on the `Button` release, just call the new method. So add a method like:

```
def position_and_open_min_down(self, button):
    # open the DropDownList
    self.min_down.open(button)

    # now adjust its position
    self.min_down.x -= self.min_down.width/2
```

And in the `kv`, change the `Button` rule to:

```
    Button:
        pos_hint:{'center_x': .27, 'center_y': .6}
        size_hint: .03, .05
        on_release: root.position_and_open_min_down(self)
```

As noted, this works, but then the `DropDown` slides back. The only way I could come up with to fix that is to override the `DropDown` method that actually calculates the position of the `DropDown`. This is messing with a private method and is highly discouraged. Any changes to the `DropDown` class may mess this up. I would recommend putting up with the slight inconvenience of using the `DropDown` without this modification. Having made disclaimers, here is a possible solution:

Create a new class (`MyDropDown`):

```
class MyDropDown(DropDown):
    def _reposition(self, *largs):
        super(MyDropDown, self)._reposition(*largs)
        widget = self.attach_to
        if not widget:
            return
        wx, wy = widget.to_window(*widget.pos)

        # do centering calculation here
        x = wx - self.width/2

        # everything else is just to keep the DropDown inside the window
        if x < 0:
            x = 0
        win = self._win
        if not win:
            self.x = x
            return
        if x + self.width > win.width:
            x = win.width - self.width
        self.x = x
```

The `_reposition()` method is what calculates the position of the `DropDown`, and the above just recalculates the `x`.

Replace calls to `DropDown` with `MyDropDown`, and remove the

```
self.min_down.x -= self.min_down.width/2
```

You can also revert the `Button` action to:

```
on_release: root.min_down.open(self)
```

Comment: It's working when I open the app for the first time. But when I resize the window, it begins to align again on the left side.

Comment: Yes, but you can add the position adjustment to the `resizing` method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700800/how-can-i-define-kivy-dropodown-list-max-height-according-to-the-screen-height/57702118?noredirect=1#comment101848061_57702118)

Comment: I've tried to put this `self.min_down.x -= self.min_down.width / 2.5` inside the resizing method. When it opens it is in the right position. But then immediately slides to the left.